# ValueError: time data 'March 13, 2019 11:02 AM' does not match format 'MMM d, YYYY h:mm a'

Tags: python, date

I am trying to format the time data "March 13, 2019 11:02 AM" with "MMM d, YYYY h:mm a"

```
date_time_str = "March 13, 2019 11:02 AM"
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, 'MMM d, YYYY h:mm a')
```

Not sure why I am getting this error,

```
ValueError: time data 'March 13, 2019 11:02 AM' does not match format 'MMM d, YYYY h:mm a'
```

I tried to solve it, referred questions by other site members.but no luck.

Comment: The date format that you were trying to use would be almost correct in Excel or Windows regional settings. But they are not universal conventions. The "does not match" message is intended as a hint to *read* (or re-read) *the documentation*. Many programmers have to do that every time they write a call to `strptime()`. It's okay to concede that you are one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `format` string is written incorrectly. It should be as follows:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')
```

This works as you intended. For more info, check this site: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior.